# How to validate LedgerJournal from code?

Tags: import, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm inserting o **LedgerJournal** from code.

When I finished to insert a record in tables *LedgerJournalTable* and *LedgerJournalTrans* I have to **validate** and **post** this Journal.

For to **post** a Ledger I use the class `LedgerJournalPost` , my code is :

```
LedgerJournalPost::postJournal(_myJournal , NoYes::NO);
```

This way is good to post, but before I want to **validate** the journal.

What is the class ? Or what is the good way ?

On **LedgerForm** there is a *Validate Button* , under I have this MenuItem : `LedgerJourChk` (Label:*Validate*), but I don't find the class.

Thanks all,

enjoy!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't find the class is because the form method `\Forms\LedgerJournalTable\Methods\enableButtonsActive` is where they set the menu item to use in a line similar to `checkJournal.menuItemName(menuitemActionStr(LedgerJourChkLJTransCustPaym));`

You would use one of the classes `LedgerJournalCheck` or `LedgerJournalCheckPost`.

See this accepted answer to see an example use:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6873379/1179573